# Why aren't the edit stats incrementing?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've been updating some empty tags, but my edit stats aren't showing an increase. Happily, I'm getting rep credit, but my edit numbers are frozen at 201. Is this a known issue, or am I just being impatient and the system just needs to catch up?

Comment: On a similar note, I offered and awarded a bounty on a question not my own, but didn't get either of the associated badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a server migration this week-end. It's possible that some stats weren't updating as fast as they normally do, or that some items went uncounted. The migration should be over now, can you check again if your stats are what they should be? If they aren't, please indicate where you read the wrong number.

Comment: The editor stats on the Users page show me with a total of 201 for the year, and zero for the week/month/quarter when I had recently submitted 17 tag/tag excerpt suggestions.

Comment: @MajorStackings I see. I'll relay that. It might not be fixed today, I think the devs have gone to rest after pulling overtime yesterday.

Comment: Thanks. Good things come to those who wait :)

Comment: @MajorStackings - I think I vaguely recall approving 1 or more of yours, as well.

Comment: @Gilles Update: There is still something amiss. When I checked yesterday, my yearly edit count had gone up by 1.

Comment: @Gilles The edit stats *are* incrementing now, but the total is wonky. My edit count has dropped from the 201 I had before I posted this question to 44. It should be closer to 225(ish).

Comment: @MajorStackings Is it just today, or has this been going on? Because yesterday they did a live test of the server failover from New York to Oregon (you might have heard about that on the news — they didn't skimp on the datacenter flooding simulation).

Comment: @Gilles As of yesterday I noticed my 3 digit count had dropped. I know I should have a ton of tag edits. Maybe they started seperating tag edits from question edits, and I'm just seeing my question edit counts? I think there's an unpopulated column out there someplace.

Comment: @MajorStackings The only thing that should cause the edit count to drop is if posts get deleted. I don't think we've deleted many questions in the past few months. There is a monthly job that deletes tags that have a single use (something that I oppose, but in vain); if you've been writing a lot of wikis for them, I'm afraid that was a waste of time. There hasn't been a change of rule that I know of. I'll ping someone from SE to have a look.

Comment: @Gilles A quick count on the activity page suggestions tab shows me with around 189 tag edits excluding the orphan wikis and question/answer edits. My user page shows me with 44 for the year. And it is a bummer about the orphans, at least you tried. :)

Comment: ...and I'm now my edit count is at 259. It looks like they shook things back into place.